# Is “Blade Runner 2: The Edge of Human” and its sequels in continuity with “Blade Runner 2049”?

Tags: blade-runner-series, blade-runner-2049

I was surprised to find that *Blade Runner 2049* was **not** the first sequel to *Blade Runner*. That distinction goes to three novels by K. W. Jeter:

- *[Blade Runner 2: The Edge of Human](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blade_Runner_2:_The_Edge_of_Human)* (1995)
- *[Blade Runner 3: Replicant Night](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blade_Runner_3:_Replicant_Night)* (1996)
- *[Blade Runner 4: Eye and Talon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blade_Runner_4:_Eye_and_Talon)* (2000)

Given that the novels involve Deckard and Rachel, whose fates are important to *Blade Runner 2049*, do these novels fit within the continuity of that film?

<sub>And yes, I realize that the Wikipedia articles for the novels have plot summaries, but I don’t want to have them spoiled if I decide to read the books.</sub>

Comment: The novels align well with the canon of Bladerunner - The Edge of Human begins almost the day after the end of Bladerunner, with Deckard and Rachael trying to leave the city. The other two books suffered a mixed review (although PKD approved the publication of all three) and contains original characters from *Do Andriods...* and Bladerunner.

Comment: @Kevin To be clear, I am asking if they fit with *Blade Runner 2049*. For instance, if the novels say “Rachael was eaten by sharks the day after she left with Deckard”, then it would not be compatible with *2049* because that movie reveals that she died in a specific, plot-relevant way.

Comment: @Thunderforge I'm at work and don't have time to put together a full answer right now, but I would say a hard no. For details, I'd say you'd be best off reading the novels on your own. For your sanity, however, I'd say avoid them like the plague. I read them about six months ago and barely made it through.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Not really

The novel Blade Runner 2 takes place shortly after the movie Blade Runner. However, in the book (Spoilers from BR2)...

> Rachel is dying, subject to the same four-year lifespan as her replicant brethren. Deckard keeps her in a stasis capsule, waking her up only one day a year (her birthday, IIRC). By the end of the novel, Rachel is dead - her capsule had been shut down while Deckard was away, killing her. The novel ends with Deckard and Sarah Tyrell - heiress to Tyrell Corp and the human template for Rachel - assuming new identities and leaving earth for the off-world colonies. Tyrell HQ is bombed to the ground by the UN in an attempt to kill Sarah and wipe the corporation out.
>
>  The second sequel novel deals with Deckard on an orbital city making a film about his adventures - in effect, an in-universe version of the Blade Runner film; Sarah Tyrell has her own adventures as she spirals into insanity. The third novel features neither Deckard nor Sarah prominently; it's about a bounty hunter hired to find Tyrell's owl.

So, the main discrepancy between the books and the sequel film is that...

> Deckard never had the opportunity to have a child.

Comment: "it's about a bounty hunter hired to find Tyrell's owl". Of all the plots for a sequel to Blade Runner, this was not the one I would have expected.

Comment: I agree. BR2 wasn't terrible - it had a coherent, and somewhat tolerable plot. The other two were basically unreadable.

Answer (score -1):

The novels by K. W. Jeter are their own thing. They're not completely satisfactory but they help you quench your thirst if you're avid for more Blade Runner stuff. They're not, however, in line with the events depicted in Blade Runner 2049.

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. You could improve this answer by editing it to explain how you know that the novels by K. W. Jeter take place in a separate continuity, and citing any relevant evidence.